# RAILS: Separate users displaying the same content in view when should be different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am making an organizer website, where someone can organize their clients, projects, etc. But am hitting technical challenge I don't seem to know how to get around (yet).

**My Goal**:

Separate Users live in their own world, where they create their own clients which are displayed on their clients page when they are logged in and navigate to the clients page.

**Current Challenge**:

After seeding the db for separate users via the Faker gem, separate users currently show the same clients list in the index view when they navigate to the clients page, when I am hoping for them to have different strings of characters listed (representing different clients)

[image]

**What I have tried**:

I am currently adapting [RailsTutorial.org Chp11: Micropost Guide](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) to suit my  client scenario and have tried creating a SHOW, and INDEX function in the client controller, but am still fairly fuzzy on the entire GET/POST and controller actions scene, which is where I think I am hitting the technical block.

**My Code**:

*Routes.rb*

```
  get 'password_resets/newedit'

  root              'static_pages#home'
  get 'about' =>    'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' =>   'users#new'

  get 'login' =>    'sessions#new'
  #the page for new session
  post 'login' =>   'sessions#create'
  #creates a new session
  delete 'logout' =>'sessions#destroy'
  #deletes the session
  get 'clients' => 'clients#show'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

*Clients.html.erb*

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Clients') %>

<div class="clients-container container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Add pagination later for multiple folders over multiple pages --> 
    <% if @user.clients.any? %>
        <%= render @clients %> 
        <!-- render produces the following code: 
            from the partial file;

            <div class="col-md-2 client-folder" style="margin: 10px" id="client - <%= client.id %>">
            <span class="clientName" ><%= client.client_name %></span> <br>
            <span class="contactName"><%= client.contact_name %></span>
            </div>
        -->

        <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Clients_controller.rb*

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = current_user
        @clients = @user.clients.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end 
end
```

*User_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only:    [:edit, :update] #restricted areas
  before_action :admin_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end 

  def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render :layout => 'signup.html.erb'
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to focus. Please check your e-mail to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #Handle a successful update.
      flash[:success] = "Your information has been updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end 

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy # destroys users
    flash[:success] = "Users deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end 
  private 

    #Confirms a  logged-in user. 
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        #While false...
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end 
    end 

    #Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user=User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
        #If another user gets access to one user's id#
        #Rails gets the user profile id and tests it 
        #against the id of User logged in current 
    end     

    def user_params
      # 'strong parameter' to prevent mass assignment vulnerability 
      # user_params privatize to limits external exposure
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,
                                   :password,:password_confirmation)
    end 

    # Confirms admin user 
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end 
end
```

*Partial portion of: seed.db*

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(3)
50.times do
    client_name = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    contact_name = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    contact_email = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    contact_phone = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    client_address = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    users.each { |user| user.clients.create!(client_name: client_name,
                                             contact_name: contact_name,
                                             contact_email: contact_email,
                                             contact_phone: contact_phone,
                                             client_address: client_address) }
    end
```

If you would be so kind as to point out what I am not seeing technically, it would be much appreciated !

edit; I hope additional pictures can help:
[image]

edit 2: 
Attaching the final working code for anyone who might find useful thanks to @GoGoCarl 's input:

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(3)
50.times do
    users.each { |user| 
    client_name = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    contact_name = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    contact_email = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    contact_phone = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    client_address = Faker::Lorem.characters(10)

    user.clients.create!(client_name: client_name,
                                             contact_name: contact_name,
                                             contact_email: contact_email,
                                             contact_phone: contact_phone,
                                             client_address: client_address) }

    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your seeding loop needs to be inverted.  You are creating 50 clients, and for each group, you iterate the users and add the clients.  This means each user will get that same set of clients.  Not same by ID, but same by appearance (field names).  Each of the three users get a client with the given pre-set properties (name, email, etc)

Instead, invert the loop; iterate first over each user, then for each user create 50 clients, and add those 50 clients to that user.

Now, all your clients should be distinct from one another, instead of sharing the same fields.

Note: this loop would also work if you didn't assign variables, and just do:

```
user.clients.create!(client_name: Faker::Lorem.characters(10),
  contact_name: Faker::Lorem.characters(10),
  contact_email: Faker::Lorem.characters(10),
  contact_phone: Faker::Lorem.characters(10),
  client_address: Faker::Lorem.characters(10))
```

Then, each time create is called, a new set of random characters would be generated instead. Still, I think inverting the loop makes the code more obvious. But, that's all relative!